# Implementing Regular Expression in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to make a c++ program to match particular regular expressions, I used DevCpp and the library

```
#include<regex.h>
```

. It's not working, I don't know why.

It's showing: `[Error] regex.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: The standard C++ header for [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) is `<regex>`

Answer (score 2):

The headers from the C++ standard library don't have `.h` on the end. In this case the correct include is:

```
#include <regex>
```

You also need to ensure that your compiler supports c++11. In the case of GCC you need to be careful that you are using a recent version  (4.9 or newer), libstdc++ provided a `regex` header long before they had provided a working implementation.